# Export to specified Excel Cell using Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2016

I've VBA code that exports data to Excel. About halfway through, the data stops going where it's supposed to.

If I want to start at BA4, it starts at BA3.
If I want to start at BD127, it starts at BD3.

I can have whatever field I want, provided it starts at row 3.

Here is a section that works:

```vb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SMG 6 AM-AR")

recCount = rec.Fields.Count
topLeft = "AM4"
botRight = "AR" & recCount
With objXL
    .Visible = False
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(mypath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(2)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.Range(topLeft, botRight).CopyFromRecordset rec
End With
wb.Save
```

Here is a section that refuses to paste where I instruct it to:

```vb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SMG 7 BL - BN 2")

recCount = rec.Fields.Count
topLeft = "BL4"
botRight = "BN" & recCount
With objXL
    .Visible = False
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(mypath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(2)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.Range(topLeft, botRight).CopyFromRecordset rec
End With
wb.Save
```

Comment: Delete `on error resume next` to be sure that `ws` is set correctly. If there is no second sheet in that workbook plus you receive no error on `ws.Range(...).CopyFromRecordset` the values will be written to the previous `ws`

Comment: Thanks, @ike.   I commented out that line but the results are unchanged.  ws is set right.  The workbook has 3 sheets.  What's interesting is that I can move around these blocks of code (there are about 9 of them) and no matter what order, the ones that work continue to do so, and the ones that don't continue to paste 1 row above where they should.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a generic sub that takes parameters.
Then call this sub for each of your queries

Something like this - not tested!!!

```vb
public sub insertData(objXL as Excel.Application, _ 
                      myPath as String, QueryName as string, _
                      byval startAddress as string)

dim rec as Recordset
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(QueryName)

dim wb as Excel.Workbook, ws as Excel.worksheet
With objXL
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(mypath)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(2)
    ws.Range(startAddress).CopyFromRecordset rec
  End With
  wb.Save
End with 

End Sub
```

Your main sub might look like

```vb
Sub InsertAll

....

insertData objXL, "c:\wb1.xlsx", "SMG 6 AM-AR", "AM4"
insertData objXL, "c:\wb2.xlsx", "SMG 7 BL - BN 2", "BL4"

....

End sub
```

This way you can be sure that every step is really working the same way. And it is much easier to spot errors within the parameter section of each sub-call.